# Pagination and .htaccess

Tags: php, pagination

I am currently showing results using the following url index.php?id=1 and using .htaccess to rewrite it like cat/sub-cat/ and i am using pagination and the url to the next page is index.php?page=2 etc but i can't seem to get the pagination to work with my .htaccess rewritten url so for example threads/thread-name/ shows the page fine etc but when i click on the next page link i just get the same page, if i use the normal url such as index.php?id=1&page=2 that works fine but i can't seem to get it to work in a nicer fashion

Hope that explains the issue clearly :)

Comment: You'll need to post your rewrite rules

Comment: i am rewriting like this RewriteRule postname/ index.php?id=1 to display the post and this works fine but the pagination won't work with the new 'vanity' url

Comment: And what is the url of the second page? /postname/2 ?

Comment: well i have been trying to get page/2/ but postname/2/ could work as well but i can't seem to get it to work at all, the RewriteRule for the pagination seems to conflict with the RewriteRule for the post

Comment: Posting your current .htaccess would help.

Comment: hi i did, i am accessing posts using index.php?id=1 and rewriting that to postname/ within the same page i am using pagination which accesses the next page using index.php?page=2 if use index.php?id=1&page=2 it works fine but if i try postname/?page-=2 it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, then you need a rewriterule something like this:

```
RewriteRule ([a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9]?) index.php?id=$1&page=$2
```

Which then directs /mycoolpage/2 to index.php?id=mycoolpage&page=2 etc

And if the last number is not present, then the `page` query parameter will simply be blank (so you'd assume `page=1`)

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for the input, that sounds just like what i want it to do but i really don't know much about .htaccess (yet) so would i put this before my RewriteRule postname/ index.php?id=1 rule ?

Comment: probably you should replace it David.

Comment: Hi i have just tested this out but will have to change the way i retrieve posts as id in my script is a number not the postname therefore i would have to use a url like /1/ instead of /postname/ for it to work...