# Extending rewrite rule via .htaccess to include pagination fields and values in query string

Tags: .htaccess

I have a page on a site that displays images according to records it pulls from a database.  The page uses a query string for the purpose, like this:

```
www.example.com/category.php?category=cars
```

But I wanted to have a "pretty" address in the browser for this, to look like this:

```
www.example.com/category/cars
```

So I placed this directive in the root .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^category/(\w+)/?$ category.php?category=$1
```

This did the trick: now, a link to:

```
www.example.com/category/cars
```

... fetches the page contents that would have been fetched by:

```
www.example.com/category.php?category=cars
```

(and that latter original query string version still works).

But now I'd like to introduce pagination into category.php, so that it will take two query strings: "category" (as before) and now "page" as well.

My question is, how can I amend/extend the .htaccess directive, so that a link to:

```
www.example.com/category/cars/9
```

... fetches the output of:

```
www.example.com/category.php?category=cars&page=9
```

Also, could such an extending of the rewrite work so that, if a site visitor manually changed what obviously appears to be the page number, say from:

```
www.example.com/category/cars/9
```

to:

```
www.example.com/category/cars/2
```

... the address would actually fetch the corresponding "page":

```
www.example.com/category.php?category=cars&page=2
```

(if it exists as per the pagination)?

Answer (score 0):

see this:

[Pagination and .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514756/pagination-and-htaccess)

and consider a empty page as a first page, for example

Comment: I don't seem to be having any success applying examples from that post.  The format for the query string page is `www.example.com/category.php?category=cars&page=3`

Comment: The fields will always be "category" and "page" - just their values change.

Comment: RewriteRule ([^/]+)/([0-9]?) index.php?category=$1&page=$2

Comment: Tiago - thank you very much for your comment and help, but I stupidly made an error in describing what I needed.  I actually need the .htaccess directive to work so that a link to `www.example.com/cars/9` fetch the output of `www.example.com/category.php?category=cars&page=9`.  (In other words I don't need the "pretty" link to include the `/category/` part.)  My apologies for the confusion.  Can this be done?  Thank you.

Comment: I would only want the rewrite rule to work for the category.php page, by the way.

Comment: OK I see from [http://www.9lessons.info/2009/11/pretty-urls-with-htaccess-file.html] that the following appears to work: `RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ category.php?category=$1&page=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)/$ category.php?category=$1&page=$2` ... though I don't know why the second variant with the extra forward slash is required.

Comment: Following my implementation of the rewrite rule I found at [http://www.9lessons.info/2009/11/pretty-urls-with-htaccess-file.html] and in reply to Tiago...  Another thing I don't understand is this: after implementing the rewrite rule, in category.php I had to change all my links to stylesheets, images etc to be "one more level up" - eg changing `<img src="images/picture.jpg" alt="" />` to `<img src="../images/picture.jpg" alt="" />`.

Comment: I can (sort of) understand why this is necessary when linking to the new form of `example.com/cars/9` after the rewrite rule, as the rewrite rule makes the page appear to be in a subfolder.  But - if I click a link to the "original" form of category.php, meaning, to `example.com/category.php?category=cars&page=9` - the page displays correctly, despite having all those links moved "one level up".  I'd have thought that the need to alter links to be "one further level up" would have only applied to the fetching of `example.com/cars/9` and not to `example.com/category.php?category=cars&page=9`.

Comment: What's even weirder is that there are PHP includes in the category.php file which **don't** seem to need the alteration to "one further level up" at all, in either case; that is, I still write them as `include('myincludefile.php');` - not as `include('../myincludefile.php');`, yet the files are included successfully whether I'm linking to `example.com/cars/9` or to `example.com/category.php?category=cars&page=9`.  I hope this makes sense.  It all works, but I don't understand these (to me, apparent) anomalies, which is frustrating.

Comment: One more thing - I seem to have to make the link to the "pretty" URL include the first page, like `example.com/cars/1` - I can't just have `example.com/cars` (which I'd like) as it returns a 404 since there is no such "cars" directory.  Is there a further modification to the rules I found that could accommodate this as well?

Comment: OK, I've just slapped my forehead realising that the rewrite doesn't apply to the php but only to the html output (duh!) but I'd still like to know how I can modify the rule further to stop the 404 with just `example.com/cars` (ie, no page)